# Return type of recursive functions to parse arrays

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function to adapt a simple dictionary to a Select prop. It just receives an entity or an array of entities and returns ir accordingly adapted, basically changing my props names to `value` and `label`.

**EDIT**: sorry for not putting the type and variable!

```js
const selectValueTranformationKeys = {
  mobilePhone: { valuePropName: "mobilePhoneId", labelPropName: "description" },
  tv: { valuePropName: "tvId", labelPropName: "description" },
  pc: { valuePropName: "pcId", labelPropName: "description" },
};

type SelectOption = {
  label: string;
  value: any;
};

export const transformIntoSelectValue = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  entity: T | T[],
  entityType: keyof typeof selectValueTranformationKeys,
  params?: { disabled?: boolean; tags?: string[] },
): SelectOption | SelectOption[] => {
  if (Array.isArray(entity)) {
    const resp = entity.map(item => transformIntoSelectValue(item, entityType, params))
    return resp // Error here: Type '(SelectOption | SelectOption[])[]' is not assignable to type 'SelectOption | SelectOption[]'.
  }

  // An external dictionary containing the respective pairs from my different possible entities:
  const value = entity[selectValueTranformationKeys[entityType].valuePropName as keyof T];
  const label = `${entity[selectValueTranformationKeys[entityType].labelPropName as keyof T]}`;
  return {
    label,
    value,
  };
};

const exampleTv = {
  tvId: 3,
  description: "Samsung"
}
```

I think it gives me that error because of the recursion: Typescript transpiler can't understand the array will only be returned inside the `if`, so inside the `if` it infers that the recursive call could return an array also, and in this case the `.map()` of a recursive could also return an array os arrays (which is not the set return type).

I can solve it by casting the return inside the `if`:
`return resp as SelectionOption[]`. But I believe casting should be our last resource.

Does someone imagine how to solve this without the casting?

Comment: Sorry! There it is!

Comment: I'm confused, with `T extends Record<string, unknown>`, the compiler will reject most arrays as input because there's no string index signature. But then `Array.isArray()` is useless. Maybe you mean `T extends object`? Could you show a [mre] which demonstrates how it's supposed to work? Note that if you do fix it so that it accepts arrays, by what reasoning do you prohibit an input like `[[exampleTv]]`? Your recursion certainly could result in an arbitrarily nested array (otherwise why would it be recursive)? Could you [edit] to clarify what's going on and why your types are the way they are?

Comment: What did you do? I don’t understand, sorry.

Comment: I edited adding the missing types and variable.

Comment: Could you re-read my first comment and address the points in there? [Look at the error at the bottom here](https://tsplay.dev/mMLEZN). Why is that happening? Why constrain `T` to `Record<string, unknown>` when that *rejects* arrays? Is this a [mre]? What are your use cases?

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your time and patience. I missed this because I had refactored it before asking, and I control-z'ed until the initial version, but I forgot the last control-Z. It should accept arrays, now it is correct.

Comment: Either you do or you don't intend to support nested array inputs.  If you do, then you will get nested array outputs [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/NBdpzW) and so your return type is incorrect. If you don't, then what exactly is the goal of making your function *recursive* so it can call *itself*? I could imagine doing [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAaAvm), which is no longer recursive, and the return type is now accurate. So what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Yep, your solution was also were I ended up being.  I just tried to discover if I can do without nesting the functions -- but it is silly, the recursive call is a nesting anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a good reason for `transformIntoSelectValue()` to be recursive, unless you want to allow for the input and output types to be arbitrarily nested arrays.  And that's the error you're getting. It is really and truly possible for the recursive call to get an array back, and therefore the return type could be a nested array. If you don't want that, you could possibly use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) or [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to prevent that:

```
return entity.flatMap(item => transformIntoSelectValueRec(item, entityType, params)); // okay
```

But there still doesn't seem to be much point in allowing it. Instead you want only one potential level of nesting. Meaning instead of calling the full `transformIntoSelectValue()` inside itself, you just call the part of it which transforms a single `T` into a single `SelectOption`.  Leading to something like this:

```
const transformIntoSelectValue = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  entity: T | T[],
  entityType: keyof typeof selectValueTranformationKeys,
  params?: { disabled?: boolean; tags?: string[] },
): SelectOption | SelectOption[] => {

  function oneEntity(entity: T): SelectOption {
    const value = entity[selectValueTranformationKeys[entityType].valuePropName as keyof T];
    const label = `${entity[selectValueTranformationKeys[entityType].labelPropName as keyof T]}`;
    return {
      label,
      value,
    };
  }
  if (Array.isArray(entity)) {
    return entity.map(oneEntity)
  } return oneEntity(entity)    
};
```

Now you definitely get back `SelectOption | SelectOption[]` with absolutely no possibility of arbitrary nesting.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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-LgKFStQGHMFhOFcvhjHEXopHkby-LUaEzG0TAGZZjmqZpox8oCIRuDytcIx8PRApPI2aHNp8opIbgwKgsu0KwjA8LkEiKJojAGLYnihIkmS+aUnSHp0ky8oiTM8gUcKgrwMKXFishTz8TKQnykOSqWgoGpaoB8C6vIBpGvAJpmhaeoubajL2rwTrzBZPrrJ6NVrGAfoBjwvCVCQGKbusMgAKK+UwCb9VSVWtrVuatWme7gFB2kwcBBbwRZPH4PFaECQwQnYf1uH4bNEmzGRMDhbJNGVHR00MdkTEcGxHH9YtiHLXxa2JSwW0Un2olRuJjQkYdx10oy8mKemmbZuNZ3qVdmlprNMN6QIU5BiGcYYNGsYRmjg0fcmamgypS79VGVAVr1-UOpOSlg6pZMfdjBYU21IzHAZF1guCugaMgeCKBsE0Coo1jyAAzPKvTFAMnhzCOGIHAYfBIzcQA)